# Autocomplete jquery , Select event is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get a list of name and Id at autocomplete. I have keypress event at textbox and called a funstion of ajax post and I am able to get list for selection. I am trying to get Id and Name. If I have  binded name in the textbox then where should I have to keep ID so that it could not be visible to user but I can use it when I have to save data. I can use hidden field but how to assign that Id to hidden field id if Select event of Autocomplete  is not working. Also, I need to change the hidden field value when another element is get selected from list.
Please Help me regarding this. Thank You.

```
    function SearchClients() {

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txt_Autocomplete").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "../PsychiatricEvaluation/SearchClients",
                        data: "{'searchtext':'" + document.getElementById('txt_Autocomplete').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.Data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.Name,
                                    value: item.id
                                }
                            }));
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            alert("hi");
                            //$("#txt_Autocomplete").val(ui.item.value);
                            $("#hdnPkClientId").val(ui.item.id);
                        },
                        change: function (e, ui) {
                            alert("changed!");
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert('Error');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: perhaps it is a CSS issue, do you have the jquery ui autocomplete css file referenced?

Comment: yes Sir and I can see it 200 OK in console.

Comment: Try replacing : 'searchtext' with 'term'.

Comment: It was a css Issue. now, I am getting another problem. My select and change event of autocomplete is not working. Can you please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Put your jQuery hookups inside of the `$(document).ready` event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txt_Autocomplete").autocomplete({ ...
});
```

Comment: Sir,I have edited above code. Please check how I have used your Idea but still not working.Even alert is not firing up.

Comment: @Sandy, take it out of that other method. You only need to hook it up once. Just put the `$(document).ready` function in a `.js` file.

Comment: @Sandy, I'm sorry but I don't follow what you're saying. You said it's not working, but otherwise it is working? Please take a second and delete those comments and be a bit more clear.

Comment: Sir, I am getting list after I put search keyword in textbox, after selecting a element from that list, I want to call select event of auto complete so that I can assign a value to hidden field , which I will be using further for saving information and here only problem lies. Select event is not working.Above code I am using.